# Is it possible to compile a Regex in Dart?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Is there a way to compile a regex to improve its performance in Dart?
In languages like C# and Java you can use RegexOptions.Compiled and Pattern.compile respectively to improve the performance of a RegEx that is used multiple times.

I've checked the RegExp and Pattern documentation but I haven't found anything like this or does Dart's RegExp works like Javscript's RegExp, which compiles the regex in the constructor?

Comment: You compile the pattern when using RegExp constructor.